# Convolution module

Tags: convolution, correlation

I am trying to apply GCC-PHAT algorithm [here](http://www.xavieranguera.com/phdthesis/node92.html) to process audio files and find delay between them. 
Im coding using Android and Java with the help of this [library](http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/res/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages/Fft.java), and comparing the results with Matlab.

Till now, everything is going right, till i get to the module part. as you can see in the article i have to calculate the `abs(convolution)`. In Matlab, the output is a Matrix (i didnt understand why). I am confused how to do that in Java, should i divide each field of the convolution output array by each field on the convolution module part like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<conv_abs.length;i++)
            {
                 G[i] = out_real[i]/conv_abs[i];

            }
```

or should i divide each number in `out_real` by the whole array `conv_abs`.

Answer (score -1):

In Matlab, every thing is treated as a matrix.  conv is the command to use for convolution.  If you share the code you used I can check and comment.

Comment: this is the code in Matlab: fft1=fft(s,wlen);      
% fft2=fft(x,wlen);        
% G12=fft1.*conj(fft2);     
% G=G12/max(abs(G12),1e-6);  
% g=real(ifft(G));          
% g=fftshift(g);

Comment: Where are you convolving?  You have commented everything except the first instruction.

Comment: no i commented to make it visible and seperate.this is the convolution:  G12=fft1.*conj(fft2);

Comment: fft2 is a reserved keyword.  Better not use it as a varaible. Do you want circular convolution or linear convolution?  If you multiply ffts and take ifft what you get is circular convolution not linear convolution.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: A lot.  Just google it.  You will find many places with examples.

Comment: yes circular convolution is the one i need here